# CRM 2011 Ribbon DisplayRule ValueRule check for null

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Quick one, I don't see any direct answers out there so I thought I'd ask. (Here is the [same question asked on the microsoft social site](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/crmdevelopment/thread/44d1187d-547d-49c5-a734-d4ad347a3a40) and it is unanswered as well)

If I have a DisplayRule and a ValueRule in that, how can I check for null? This suggested solution below apparently doesn't work (according to the linked question):

```
  <DisplayRule Id="new.incident.form.IsNotRelatedToY.DisplayRule">
    <ValueRule Field="YId" Value="null" InvertResult="true" />
  </DisplayRule>
```

Does it depend on the type of Field? If so I need it to work in two seperate cases, when YId is an entity reference, and also when YId is a string. I figure "null" cannot work for a string, because "null" is a valid string.

Anyone have a working example?

EDIT: it looks like the [ValueRule documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334317.aspx) has nothing on the subject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question, but unfortunately I don't think there's any good answer here because I think it's a bug. If you use `"null"` as the value for a string attribute in a `ValueRule` for an `EnableRule`, you'll see that the button in fact becomes enabled (or disabled depending on what you set for `InvertResult`). It just doesn't work for `DisplayRule`s. (My best guess is they just put more effort into developing `EnableRules` instead of `DisplayRules`; as mentioned in your link, there's no support for `CustomRule`s for `DisplayRules` either, though it exists for `EnableRules`.)

I'd file a bug report, but Microsoft Connect is still only accepting "suggestions" for Dynamics CRM.

Comment: Very insightful answer, thank you for sharing. I was able to reproduce the display rule not working. I will change it to an enable rule as a "good enough" solution. Also, FYI, I was referred here (https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?ln=en-us&sd=gn&x=8&y=11&c1=11524&gprid=15707&&st=1&wfxredirect=1) once to file CRM bugs. (see here for my original request: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/crmdevelopment/thread/0dd33e42-31e3-4439-b6bc-08576b0f35ad)

Answer (score 2):

It's fixed in CRM 2013. I just tested it and work