# CRM 2011 'Realtime' Custom Ribbon Rules

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

Just wondering if it is possible to set a ribbon rule which shows/hides a button group on a form based on the certain values on that form in realtime

(I want ribbon button to be hidden if a value is missing/changed/removed from the form but before the form is saved)

While I understand that it is possible to have the ribbon run custom JavaScript, i was wondering if the JavaScript is only triggered on form load or whenever certain field values have been changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`refreshRibbon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828.aspx#BKMK_refreshRibbon) function exists precisely for this purpose, and can be triggered on a field change event, but unfortunately, it only works for `EnableRules`, not `DisplayRules`. (See a very [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505040/crm-2011-ribbon-displayrule-valuerule-check-for-null) for a similar problem.)

> This function is typically used when a ribbon [**`<EnableRule>`** (RibbonDiffXml)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328073.aspx) 
>   depends on a value in the form. After your code
>   changes a value that is used by a rule, use this method to force the
>   ribbon to re-evaluate the data in the form so that the rule can be
>   applied.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll have to just go with using the enablerule node